# Flutter firebase snapshot return always 1 document when it is empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: workoutsViewModel.listenMyWorkoutsChange(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.hasData) {

        final workoutList = snapshot.data.documentChanges.map((doc) => WorkoutModel.fromMap(doc.document.data, doc.document.documentID)).toList();
        print("-- workouts " + workoutList.length.toString());

        workoutList.forEach((c) {
          print("---------- changed  document " + c.title);
        });
```

I have this code, I can listen to my snapshots, and I can delete any document in the collection.

- If I have 4 items, and delete 1, return 3 items (document or documentChanged)
- If I have 3 items, and delete 1, return 2 items (document or documentChanged)
- If I have 2 items, and delete 1, return 1 items (document or documentChanged)
- **If I have ONLY 1 item, and delete 1, return 1 items (the same) (document or documentChanged) NOT EMPTY**

But if I rerun the application, this is working and it will be empty.

Can somebody help what is going on?

**SOLUTION**

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2161

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is just a theory, as we do not have whole code and Database structure, but according to this [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/documentChanges.html) method `documentChanges` should return a list of `DocumentChange` objects.

So, in my opinion, it's not strange that it return 1 results when last document deleted. This seems to be proper behavior as among type [property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentChange/type.html) of `DocumentChange` class you have `remove` as well.

More strange for me is that you will get some more results when you are only removing the document. In such situation there should be only the one you have removed.

If you take a look on `DocumentChange` [reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentChange-class.html) there are `oldIndex` and `newIndex` properties maybe they have been changed...

If I would be in your shoes, I would log all `DocumentChange` properties and analyze what is the reason of such behavior.

I hope it will help!

Comment: I think I found the probleme https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2161

Answer (score 0):

So it is a basic firestore flutter BUG, I found, so I close this issue now.